# Incompatible Types Error with Struct C

Tags: c

I am receiving an incompatible types error as follows:

```
error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘struct cache *’ from type ‘cache’
```

I have the following structures.

```
typedef struct __region {
int size;
void *addr;
struct __region *next;
} region;

typedef struct {
int size;
int remainingSpace;
void *addr;
char *bitmap;
struct cache *parent;
struct slab *next;
} slab;

typedef struct {
int alloc_unit;
int slab_counter;
slab *S;
} cache;

typedef struct {
region *R;
cache C[8];
} memory;
```

The code I run which receives the error is:

```
memory M;
M.C[0].S->parent = M.C[0];
```

Comment: Those double underscores aren't good for keeping out name clashes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing the variable itself not its address. To pass its address, you need to use the address of (`&`) operator :

```
M.C[0].S->parent = &(M.C[0]);
```

See [this](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8l.doc/language/ref/addre.htm) for more.

Answer (score 5):

`parent` is a pointer to a `struct cache`, while `M.C[0]` is a `struct cache`. You can use the `&` operator to get a pointer to `M.C[0]` as so:

```
M.C[0].S->parent = &(M.C[0]);
```